# How to execute local Spark code on K8s cluster?

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm trying to execute my local Spark code (inside Intellij IDEA) on Spark running on local K8s cluster (rancher-desktop cluster with Spark 3.5.1 installed from Bitnami helm chart version 8.7.3).

I'm forwarding default port 7077 of my spark-master service from cluster to localhost.

Code is very simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Java Spark Example")
                .master("spark://localhost:7077")
                .config("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
                .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> csv = spark.read()
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("delimiter", ",")
                .option("header", "true")
                .csv("src/main/resources/csv/twamp.csv");
        
        csv.show();
    }
```

Error I'm getting is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1093)
com.example.App.main(App.java:32)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

(No active SparkContext.)
```

How can I connect SparkSession to K8s cluster and is it possible to execute locally written code as a job on cluster?

Can't find any resources answering that.